# Matching 2 databases of names, given first, last, gender and DOB?

Tags: mysql

I collect a list of Facebook friends from my users including First, Last, Gender and DOB. I am then attempting to compare that database of names (stored as a table in MySQL) to another database comprised of similar information.

What would be the best way to conceptually link these results, with the second database being the much larger set of records (>500k rows)?

Here was what I was proposing:

- Iterate through Facebook names
- Search Last + DOB - if they match, assume a "confident" match
- Search Last + First - if they match, assume a "probable" match
- Search Last + Lichtenstein(First) above a certain level, assume a "possible" match

Are there distributed computing concepts that I am missing that may make this faster than a sequential mySQL approach? What other pitfalls may spring up, noting that it is much more important to not have a false-positive rather than miss a record?

Comment: Maybe it's just too early in the morning, but I'm having trouble parsing "it is much more important to not have a false-positive rather than miss a record"

Comment: Heh, sorry. I'd rather skip a record I wasn't positive about than identify a record as a match that had a low possibility score.

Comment: How big is that first list of Facebook friends?    If the second DB is "much larger" and the first DB is a couple of thousand, I don't think getting into distributed computing is worth the effort.   Your searches all use last name so you might try "SELECT where lname = name from first DB", collecting the few records that pop out, and then applying your matching logic.

Comment: That's true. The list of Facebook friends will grow incrementally as users log in and authorize my app to collect their names. However, estimating 500 friends per user, it only would take 1000 users (ignoring duplicate fb profiles) to match the size of the 500k database. But good point - if my concept is good, querying just the last name (albeit 500x per user) and doing the rest in code is likely better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your idea seems like a better algorithm.

Assuming performance is your concern, you can use caching to store the values that are just being searched. You can also start indexing the results in a NoSQL database such that the results will be very faster, so that you will have better read performance. If you have to use MySQL, read about [polyglot persistence](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html).

Assuming simplicity is your concern, you can still use indexing in a NoSQL database, so over the time you don't have to do myriad of joins will spoil the experience of the user and the developer.

There could be much more concerns, but it all depends on where would you like to use it, to use in a website, or to such data analytic purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to operate on the entire set of data (as opposed to some interactive thing), this data set size might be small enough to simply slurp into memory and go from there.   Use a List to hang on to the data then create a Map> that for each unique last name points (via integer index) to all the places in the list where it exists.  You'll also set yourself up to be able to perform more complex matching logic without getting caught up trying to coerce SQL into doing it.   Especially since you are spanning two different physical databases...